# Duplicate layers in webmap Layer List

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online

I'm creating a web map in ArcGIS Online that references a MapServer from our internal server, which also has feature access enabled (FeatureServer) for editing.  When I add both services to Web AppBuilder I get duplicate layers in the Layer List (one for each layer individually, plus the "group" layer that normally shows for the MapServer alone).  Is there a way to display only the MapServer in the map and legend, but still allow feature editing through the FeatureServer?

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding the map service and the feature service to the same web map? If you want feature editing you will need to have the feature service in the map. If you do not need bot services in the map I would remove the map service.

Hope this helps

Comment: As it turns out, I did accidentally add them both.  For some reason AGOL "hides" the FeatureServer layers in the layer list when the same MapServer is present, but they all show up in the app.  What I'm looking for is a way to display the MS output, but use the FS for editing without showing it in the map or legend; unfortunately, the Edit widget apparently doesn't support custom FS URLs.  So I may be back to using custom JS... ArcGIS, y u so complicated? :(

Comment: Are you trying not to expose the feature service in the web app builder app and have that as something pointed towards the public? While you would have another map with the feature service in it that would be used for making edits/updates to the features in the map?

Comment: "While you would have another map with the feature service in it that would be used for making edits" That's a possibility. I think the problem is I want too many things at once:  I want to have a layer with several thousand features displayable at a fairly small scale (1:10000); I want the same layer to be editable; I want it to show up only once in the layer list; and I really want it all in one map.  But it seems that the only way to have both A and B is to give up either C or D.  (Even if I set scale ranges so they don't *display* simultaneously, they still both show in the layer list.)